# Qt Creator : how to exit a closing curly brace on tabulation?

Tags: qt-creator, curly-braces

There is a functionnality I really appreciate in Visual Studio : it's the ability to exit a closing curly brace by pressing the tab key. Let's illustrate what I mean for sake of clarity :

Let's assume I'm writting a simple statement (note that **^** represents the cursor's position) :

```
int a{
      ^
```

After pressing the opening curly brace **{** , VS will automatically generate the matching closing one :

```
int a{ }
      ^
```

Now, I can move the cursor outside just by pressing tab :

```
int a{}
       ^
```

It's practical because I don't have to move my fingers to press the left arrow key to exit the curly brace. How can I have the same behaviour in Qt Creator ?